# Finding ship arrivals for Australia in the 1870s?

Tags: immigration, australia, south-australia, 1870s

I am looking for information relating to the arrival of James DAY in Australia, probably with his wife Anna and four children, William and Isabel (by his first wife, Isabel Carey), and Lucy and Percy. I think the ship was the Eaton Hall and the date 1874 or 1877

Comment: Welcome to G&FH.SE! Could you let us know what searches you've tried so far, and what sources you have for the information in your question?  We encourage all new users to make use of the information in the [help] about how to write a good question.  You can use the [edit] link underneath your question to add more information.

Comment: I notice that you placed a tag for [tag:south-Australia] onto your question.  Do you have reason to believe that they arrived in South Australia rather than another of the colonies?  What is the source for you thinking that he may have arrived on the Eaton Hall? And where did the dates of 1874 and 1877 come from?  What is the first record that you have for James Day in Australia, that you can say with confidence is *your* James Day?

Comment: Thanks @PolyGeo - Obit in The Chronicle 14 Aug 1930 says JD "arrived in Australia in 1874 in the Eaton Hall" [not necessarily SA] Employed by James Martin Gawler for three years then took up land at Dowlingville, Yorke Peninsula. in 1881 married Anna Phelps, went to England and returned in 1885..."   The only Eaton Hall arrival I could find was 1877, hence suspect 1877 is a misprint or transcription mistake.

Answer (score 3):

I found an immigrant list for the arrival of the *Eaton Hall* on 25 Jun 1877 in the [South Australian Register](http://trove.nla.gov.au/ndp/del/article/40786856) and the [Evening Journal](http://trove.nla.gov.au/ndp/del/article/197701745) of 26 Jun 1877, and also the [South Australian Chronicle and Weekly Mail](http://trove.nla.gov.au/ndp/del/article/90879081) of 30 Jun 1877.

However, James Day does not appear to be listed.  All immigrants aboard the ship were single men.

I also performed this [search at the Public Records Office Victoria](http://prov.vic.gov.au/search_results?searchid=23&format=freetext&FamilyName=&GivenName=&Ship=eaton%20hall&Month=0&Monthto=0&Year=0&Yearto=0&SearchSortField1=&SearchSortField2=&SearchRecords=5000) to reveal a number of voyages (1870, 1873, 1874, 1878 and 1883) by the *Eaton Hall* to that state, and many (all?) of its passengers, but James Day once again does not appear amongst them.