# Finding George Huminski aboard Eaton Hall on 1877 voyage to South Australia

Tags: immigration, south-australia, 1870s

looking for George (sometimes Peter George) Huminski (Huminsky) who stated that he had arrived in South Australia on the Eaton Hall in 1877. I believe he worked his way out on the ship. Have checked the passenger list and he is not on it. When he married in SA in 1880 he changed his name to George Henderson.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn about our focused Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.

Comment: He does not appear to be here but I've only looked quickly: https://discovery.nationalarchives.gov.uk/details/r/C11679031

Comment: When/where did he state that he was on the Eaton Hall in 1877?

Comment: We have had a previous question about the *Eaton Hall* at https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/10081/finding-ship-arrivals-for-australia-in-the-1870s

Comment: If you do not have his birth/baptism record do you have an age at marriage or an age at death/burial on either of those records to try and find his birth year (and place)?

Comment: He stated he was on the Eaton Hall in a gaol entrance book. He had to state when he arrived in Australia and on what ship

Comment: On the birth registrations of his children he states he was born Jersey Island in 1856/57.